# How do I convert the CURL command to Guzzle HTTP Laravel

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

Do you have any idea how to convert this curl code that I want to convert to guzzle http?

```
curl -X POST "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353/stream" \
     -H "X-Auth-Email: user@example.com" \
     -H "X-Auth-Key: c2547eb745079dac9320b638f5e225cf483cc5cfdda41" \
     --form 'file=@/Users/kyle/Desktop/skiing.mp4'
```

My guzzle code

```
       $token = config('services.cloudflare.token');
        $accountId = config('services.cloudflare.acountId');
        $client = new Client();

        $response =$client->request('POST', 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/' . $accountId . '/stream', [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
                "Content-Type" => "application/json",

            ],
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'upload',
                    'filename' => 'fl',
                    'contents' => fopen($file,'r+'),
                    'name' => 'new-video.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension(),
                ],

            ]
        ]);
        echo $response->getBody();
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried so far? Do you understand the component parts of the cURL command, including what all the options do? If not, that should be your first step - there is plenty of documentation available already. Step 2 is to read the guzzle documentation and look at examples, and find the equivalent options / commands for each of the items in the original curl code. Step 3 is to run the guzzle command and see what happens. We'll _help_ you if you have a specific issue, but this isn't a free do-my-research or write-my-code service. See also [ask].

Comment: I added my guzzle codes.

Comment: Ok thanks. Well for a start, anyone can see that the headers "Authorisation" and "Content-Type" aren't the same as "X-Auth-Email" and "X-Auth-Key"...are you just guessing with that? Clearly the header names (and values) will need to be the same in both versions, for the request to be equivalent.

Comment: Also you have `file` as the form field name in the curl, but "upload" as the name in the guzzle. Aside from anything else you do, surely it's clear - again, same as the headers - that basic stuff like the names need to match!?

Comment: yes cloudflare api stated that I should use it this way. that's why I specified it as x-auth. other than that, I'm not sure if I'm making a mistake to upload files.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/5X8mNdZNBO8N I keep getting this error.

Comment: `that's why I specified it as x-auth`...yes but in the Guzzle you've specified it differently, that was my point. if you want to make a request exactly the same as the curl one then you have to use exactly the same header and field names (which I would have hoped would be obvious).

Comment: Thank you ADyson. my problem is solved. I am grateful to you

Comment: No worries. I don't understand why you couldn't see that the names were different, though.

Comment: Honestly, I think I've made so many changes that I've lost sight of it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel and Cloudflare, two of my least favorite things. 
Just use straight PHP

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353/stream');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'X-Auth-Email' => 'user@example.com',
    'X-Auth-Key' => 'c2547eb745079dac9320b638f5e225cf483cc5cfdda41',
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    'file' => new CURLFile('/Users/kyle/Desktop/skiing.mp4'),
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```